# Datetime insert conversion help needed

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, datetime

I need to insert dates which are formatted dd/mm/yyyy but unfortunately at the moment my sql is throwing up the following error from an embedded insert

***The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.***

I believe this is because the database is looking for the wrong date format. Can anyone point me to a solution to how I get the database to look for dd/mm/yyyy. I'd like to avoid converting every single date in the code because there are thousands of inserts done at the same time. Thanks

Comment: How you insert dates? Do you need to modify how ToString() works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need to insert dates which are formatted dd/mm/yyyy

Don't *think* about a particular format. Dates and times don't inherently *have* formats. Make sure your database field is of a date/time-related type, and then use parameterized SQL which specifies `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset` values. That way *your code doesn't deal with strings at all*.

The fact that the error is talking about a conversion from `varchar` suggests that you're supplying the data as strings. You shouldn't be doing that. Even if your *input* format is text, you should be converting it into its natural data type (e.g. `DateTimeOffset`) as early as possible - it'll make it a lot easier to work with the data throughout your codebase.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) and specify 103 as style.

```
convert(datetime, YourColumn, 103)
```

Or you can [set the date format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx).

```
set dateformat dmy
```

Answer (score 1):

Your date literals should always be in a safe, unambiguous and language-neutral format. So your embedded SQL should be:

```
INSERT dbo.table(column) VALUES('YYYYMMDD');
```

You can easily format the string this way in C# using `ToString()`.

But better yet, you should be using parameterized statements, passing a proper datetime parameter, and not worrying about string formatting at all.